# How can I type Chinese on MacBook Pro?

Tags: input-source

I would like to know how to type Chinese (simplified), using Pinyin, on my MacBook Pro.

I went to System Preference > Language & Text > Language, moved Chinese (simplified) on the list right after English, and then under the Input Sources tab, I check Chinese simplified and English.

After all these steps, I still have no clue how to type Chinese. (When I open TextEdit, I don't see any language selection.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After select pinyin in your input language you can open any editor like textEdit:

[image]

when you start typing you see the box (like below box) and can select your desire word.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For this and other useful info, there's a whole site:

http://www.yale.edu/chinesemac